# Textview not showing whole text in ios 8

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios8

I have problem with textview because when we set the some text into text view at run time, it not shows the whole text, its showing only few text and spaces is available in textview. So please suggest me any way to fix this problem.It was working in ios 7 but getting problem in ios 8. This is screen shot.

I have added screen shots which show the text but not whole text but when we have tapped on textview it shows full text. [image: show the text but not whole text]

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide more details about your problem, screenShot would be great! Are you building the textview in the code or from the interface ?

Comment: I have added screen shots . Thanks

Comment: when scroll down, can you see the remaining text?

Comment: No,Remaining text did not see. But when we tried to set manually some copy paste text into the xib then result was same,whole text have not show and when we have tapped on textview it show whole text on xib.

Comment: Because you did not post any code, Is this your case: You have a textView with static height and you don't change the height according to the text using boundingRectWithSize?

Comment: Or do you have auto-layout checked in the xib file attributes?

Comment: I have found Solution with these two lines
[textView.layoutManager ensureLayoutForTextContainer:StudentInterventionList.textContainer];
    [textView layoutIfNeeded];